# 404 errors GCP API gateway multiple cloud run backends

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, aws-api-gateway, google-cloud-run, api-gateway

I'm trying to secure multiple cloud run services with gcp Api gateway, which integrates firebase jwt auth. I attempted at first securing just one API with the following schema and all went fine:

```
    # openapi2-run.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: memsy-gateway
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Cloud Run backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
      - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
x-google-backend:
  address: https://mnemonic-api-staging-ue.a.run.app
securityDefinitions:
  jwt_auth:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: 'implicit'
    type: 'oauth2'
    x-google-issuer: 'https://securetoken.google.com/the-journey-method'
    x-google-jwks_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com'
    x-google-audiences: 'the-journey-method, https://mnemonic-api-staging-ue.a.run.app'
paths:
  /mnemonic-api:
    post:
      security:
        - jwt_auth: []
      summary: Mnemonic API
      operationId: mnemonics
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: input
        description: string to process
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/InputString'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: object
        '400':
          description: invalid input, object invalid
    options:
      operationId: create-cors
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
            
definitions:
  InputString:
    type: object
    properties:
      input:         
        type: string
      title:         
        type: string
    required:
      - input
      - title
```

I then tried to secure two services using the following schema but am now getting 404 errors on the paths in the config. I can also access the backends via their cloud run urls without any jwt token, so I'm wondering what's wrong in my config?

```
  # openapi2-run.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: memsy-gateway
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Cloud Run backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
      - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  jwt_auth:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: 'implicit'
    type: 'oauth2'
    x-google-issuer: 'https://securetoken.google.com/the-journey-method'
    x-google-jwks_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com'
    x-google-audiences: 'the-journey-method, https://mnemonic-api-staging-ue.a.run.app, https://backend-dql-flask-uc.a.run.app'
paths:
  /mnemonic-api:
    post:
      security:
        - jwt_auth: []
      summary: Mnemonic API
      operationId: mnemonics
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://mnemonic-api-staging-ue.a.run.app
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: input
        description: string to process
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/InputString'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: object
        '400':
          description: invalid input, object invalid
    options:
      operationId: create-cors
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
  /dql/deleteFolder:
    post:
      security:
        - jwt_auth: []
      summary: Dql
      operationId: deleteFolder
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://backend-dql-flask-uc.a.run.app
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: input
        description: user and id strings
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Dql'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: object
        '400':
          description: invalid input, object invalid
    options:
      operationId: create-cors-dql
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
            
definitions:
  InputString:
    type: object
    properties:
      input:         
        type: string
      title:         
        type: string
    required:
      - input
      - title
  Dql:
    type: object
    properties:
      user:         
        type: string
      id:         
        type: string
    required:
      - user
      - id
```

Comment: Can you check what are the logs on Cloud Run, if you have entries? In addition, can you share the expected target endpoint for each one of these definition?

Comment: Nothing to see in the logs. In terms of endpoints, they're just paths on the end of gateway url correct? e.g.: https://my-gateway.ue.gateway.dev/mnemonic-api   and  https://my-gateway.ue.gateway.dev/dql/deleteFolder.

Comment: And what is the URL that you request on the API Gateway?

Comment: I want to understand if 'my-gateway.ue.gateway.dev/mnemonic-api' and 'my-gateway.ue.gateway.dev/dql/deleteFolder' are the exact urls for your endpoints or you have edited out the project specific details for privacy sake? You need to be using the project specific urls that look something like 'my-gateway-XXXXXXXX.ue.gateway.dev',

Comment: Yep, just edited them out for privacy's sake, using the correct one in practice.

Comment: Okay.I understand its a 404 error message, but can you check your cloud logs? Also look for errors in the same time frame you deployed this gateway, If there are any error logs present please add it in your question. You can do one more thing, right click -> Inspect on your web page that is giving a 404 error because I don't see anything wrong in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is not clear honestly - with trial and error I could make it work by matching the path on the openapi definition with the path in my webserver router instead of giving the openapi definition the host only, for example:

```
paths:
  /mnemonic-api:
    post:
      security:
        - jwt_auth: []
      summary: Mnemonic API
      operationId: mnemonics
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://mnemonic-api-staging-ue.a.run.app/mnemonic-api
```

Comment: Thanks! This issue took a lot of time to resolve :(